# Why wget doesn't verify SSL certificates?

Tags: linux, ssl, wget, fedora

I have a problem with my *Fedora 8* installation. It looks that **`wget`** doesn't know how to verify SSL certificates any more. It's strange because I have another *Fedora 8* box which I believe has the same configuration and it works!

How can I make it work without using `--no-check-certificate` switch?

This is a sample output:

```
wget https://www.google.com
--2011-09-23 00:11:13--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.230.146, 74.125.230.147, 74.125.230.148, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.146|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

**EDIT**

I have this file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file and when I run **`wget`** with `--ca-certificate` switch pointing to this file everything goes fine. Where should this file be placed so that I don't need to use the switch?

BTW: `curl` and `links` work fine, but `lynx` also complains: *"SSL error:unable to get local issuer certificate"* so this is not only `wget`'s issue...

Comment: Why do you even *have* a Fedora 8 installation?

Comment: Fedora 9, 10, 11, 12, and 13 aren't even supported anymore.

Comment: I'm aware this is an ancient OS no longer supported but I hope that this is just some kind of a configuration problem which might be easily solved by someone experienced so that I don't need to upgrade the whole system.

Comment: what is the version of wget you are using ?

Comment: GNU Wget 1.11.1 (Red Hat modified)

Comment: I have solve my problem using this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320340/crontab-to-use-wget-without-sertificate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default wget will check for certificates in the path defined in openssl conf file /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf (no sure whether the path is correct for fc8). Please check the openssl configuration file and confirm that the paths are correct. May be it is openssl, that need to be corrected.

Comment: It was a problem with openssl - cert.pem file was missing in /etc/pki/tls. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

I had problems with wget not finding my certificates so I installed ca-certificates

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

then I edited:

```
sudo vi /etc/wgetrc
```

and added

```
ca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs
```

or you can just use this command to append it to the end:

> ```
> printf "\nca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc
> ```

Comment: alternatively it worked for me if I used `wget https://myurl --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs/` but I don't want to have to type that every time, aint nobody got time for that ;-)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: CentOS 7: `sudo yum upgrade ca-certificates`

Answer (score 5):

Your system doesn't trust the signature chain for Google's cert.

They also aren't presenting the full certificate chain, just their issuer's certificate; not 100% up to par, but certainly nothing that should stop you from validating the chain.

Your ancient system is likely to have an equally ancient set of trusted root certificate authorities.

Trust the right VeriSign cert ([here](http://www.verisign.com/cgi-bin/support/rootcert/getrootcert.cer)), and you should be good.

Comment: How exactly do I "trust" the VeriSign cert?

Comment: Probably needs to be put in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Comment: This dir didn't exist but I created it and copied the cert files - it didn't help :(

Comment: Not sure where the certificates directory is located in that OS, then.  `grep` around!

Answer (score 4):

You need to gather a list of the root certificates that you wish to trust and tell `wget` how to find them using either the `--ca-certificate` or `--ca-directory` option. You may already have one in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` if you have the appropriate package installed.